# Enthalpy of Fuels

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion, fuel

I am running some analysis on an engine cycle through matlab using TMATS with Cantera. I am looking to change the fuel from the default to a blend of ammonia and hydrogen. In order to do this I have to generate some tables for these species and then define the enthalpy of the fuel which is what I am confused about.

**Background**

From the documentation:
"Additionally, in any model that uses generated tables the burner modules must be set to use enthalpy. It should be noted that Cantera makes use of enthlapy values that include the heat of formation (the default tables do not) and the enthalpy value chosen for the burner must reflect this. Example values for jet fuel include LHV equal to 18400 BTU/lbm (used with the default gas tables and does not include heat of formation) and enthlapy (used with Cantera generated gas tables and including heat of formation) equal to -1200 BTU/lbm. Note, negative numbers are okay, since the enthalpy is based on a reference zero value."

From the documentation I can make out that the enthalpy seems to be the LHV plus the heat of formation. In my research I was unable to find the heat of formation for kerosene but I did find the LHV (18400) and HHV (19800) which the difference of gave -1400 BTU/lbm. This is not exactly the -1200 BTU/lbm so I was unsure if this was the method to use in defining the enthalpy for my new fuel blend.

Any clarification on how to exactly define this enthalpy is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The difference between LHV and HHV has nothing to do with heat of formation. For kero, see H sub (f,298k) in Table 1 - https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20000065620/downloads/20000065620.pdf. There are several different units and different (not-so-much) standard temps, and all, including the program's built-in values, must be consistent. Good luck, this is forever and always a PITA.

Comment: wiki has the others - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_enthalpy_of_formation